Simulate an Audio Device in Debian
I'm trying to run the latest version of Stardew Valley in a Docker container to run it as a server setup (for the record, I own the game and am using my own purchased copy to do this, per this repository's instructions). It's worth noting that I'm specifically running into this error with the Stardew Valley Expanded mod installed, in case that context helps anything. This container will be running a Debian install.
When I try to run it, I get the following error:
Game.Initialize() caught exception initializing XACT.
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.NoAudioHardwareException (0x80004005): OpenAL device could not be initialized, see console output for details.
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.OpenALSoundController..ctor() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Platform\Audio\OpenALSoundController.cs:line 117
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.OpenALSoundController.EnsureInitialized() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Platform\Audio\OpenALSoundController.cs:line 300
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.Initialize() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Audio\SoundEffect.cs:line 196
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect..ctor(MiniFormatTag codec, Byte[] buffer, Int32 channels, Int32 sampleRate, Int32 blockAlignment, Int32 loopStart, Int32 loopLength) in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Audio\SoundEffect.cs:line 153
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.WaveBank..ctor(AudioEngine audioEngine, String waveBankFilename, Boolean streaming, Int32 offset, Int32 packetsize) in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Audio\Xact\WaveBank.cs:line 276
   at StardewValley.Game1.Initialize() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\Farmer\Farmer\Game1.cs:line 2229

From what I can tell, that error message comes from MonoGame.Framework, in case that adds any context for investigation on what needs to be handled. Here's a link to the error message in that framework.
So it looks like I need a sound device of some sort, which obviously my Docker container won't have. I'm thinking if I can simulate enough of an audio device that will satisfy this requirement, that'll get me past this error. But I'm not sure how to do that. Any instructions I've seen (including using pulseaudio) seem to outline how to get the audio piped through to the host system so I can hear the audio, but honestly I don't need to hear it at all, I just need the game to think it's set up. Is this possible?

hm, is this Wine or WSL or something else?

Technically I am running the container on Windows, but I am looking to run it on a Linux VPC setup at some point. I just didn't want to subscribe to a VPC without knowing if it would work at all.

I mean, AWS, Hetzner, Azure and many others sell you servers to rent by the minute or hour; very little financial risk there :) But yeah, you running on WSL changes the way your sound system works, a bit. I don't know whether you're, for example, running Pipewire (you're almost certainly not using pulseaudio anymore, that's been superseeded by pipewire), which typically sets up an ALSA software sound device for programs that interact with ALSA. If that was the case, you'd basically be done – "simulate an audio device" is a bit of an inversion of what's happening: all audio devices that user …

… software should interact with should be some sort of software abstraction, as otherwise only one program would be able to control volume, there'd be some question of how different programs can output sound simultaneously and such. So, all sound interfaces that you get via a driver from your OS are "simulated", in a way :) Anyways, as said, yes, ALSA and pipewire can do that, out of the box, no extra tools needed.

What's the setup look like for that? I've found this and was looking at it, but I'm not sure quite sure if this is accomplishing what I'm looking to do. https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/wiki/Container-sound:-ALSA-or-Pulseaudio

if it starts with docker, it's not what you want, probably. The setup, as said, depends on whether you're running a sound server or not, and what you want to do with the device afterwards. I'm not quite clear about either part!

In my current setup, I'm on a Windows machine running a Docker container that run Debian. I'm okay if it wants to share the sound device, but ultimately I don't need the sound, I just need the game to think it has a sound device.

have you tried setting up an ~/.asoundrc inside that container that specifies a dummy device? In general, WSL can play sound through the host windows, but I don't know how docker on windows works specifically, that's all a bit far away from Linux.

Hmm I'm not familiar with how, so I'll have to look into that.
